# Design Pattern for Object History including deletion

Tags: history-tracking

We want to implement a history visualization functionality for our custom Team functionality.

We have the following data model:
[image: Data Model]

We want to track changes off attributes values on TeamMember__c, but also when a TeamMember__c was added or deleted. 
Architecturally, we currently see 2 ways of implementing this:

1. Use SFDC field history and a custom isDeleted__c flag on TeamMember__c
2. Custom TeamMemberHistory__c object to capture all changes from TeamMember__c

Both approaches have their downsides, therefore my question: is SFDC providing any other means of implementing this, or is there any other design pattern for this (in my opinion) quite common problem.

Comment: what did you go for in the end? Currently facing a similar requirement and the deleted history is an issue as well.

Comment: We will go for option 1 with a custom isDeleted flag.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with all limitations of [Field History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=5) out of the box, then I would use that for field changes. The main limitation is the free retention period of 18-24 months but you can purchase longer retention. #2 limitation is 255 char limit on the changed field.

Else, go with your custom scheme.

Comment: We are aware of the field history tracking limitations and we can live with it. Our problem is dealing with the history of deleted records.